# 500 error for clean url mod re-write

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rest

Thanks to everyone who has helped me with my clean URL quest. I'm almost there but want to lick this last thing.

#### .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

#REMOVE THIS LINE ON SITE LAUNCH!
RewriteBase /~accountName/

#Hide .php extensions for cleaner URLS
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

#calendar-expanded REST-ful URLs
RewriteRule ^calendar-expanded(/.*)?$ calendar-expanded.php$1 [L]

Options All -Indexes

<IfModule mod_security.c>
    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

# propagate php.ini file to all sub-directories
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/accountName/public_html/php.ini
```

#### my working url

`www.example.com/calendar-expanded/4/mother-mother-in-concert/`

#### a broken url

`www.example.com/calendar/12/another-band-live/`

There is no mod re-write for `calendar/` obviously.  My question is, do I absolutely need a rule for every page to avoid internal server errors if someone accidentally browses to the wrong page?  The broken url is an example of that. I'd really love for the browser to return a 404 error instead.

I'm looking for a cond/rule that will cover "all other" urls except `calendar-expanded`. Is this doable?

Thanks. (@Gumbo I'm looking hopefully in your direction!)

Comment: What does the server’s error log say? And maybe you should also consult mod_rewrite’s logging feature (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteloglevel).

Comment: @Gumbo.. thanks.  I'm on a shared hosting server so I don't have access to the main logs and the rewrite.log file isn't being written to for a reason that escapes the admins.  The main log looks like this: [Mon Jan 25 15:42:31 2010] [error] [client my.server.ip.address] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: @jeerose: Do you use any other rules?

Comment: @Gumbo, updated original to reflect entire .htaccess

Comment: @jeerose: And is there a file or directory with the name *calendar* or a similar name?

Comment: @Gumbo: Yes, but there's no rewrite to handle the /12/etc after it. Right now I want it to throw a 404 not found error rather than a 500 if someone mistypes a URL. All pages that actually exist are displayed perfectly. (i.e., www.example.com/our_centre or www.example.com/calendar-expanded/4/whatever-else/). But if you try to tack anything onto for example /calendar .... 500.

Comment: @jeerose: The *MultiViews* option could cause this behavior. Try to disable it with `Options -Multiviews`.

Comment: Everything still functions exactly the same way with `Options -Multiviews` before the `Rewrite Engine on`  :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could reconstruct this behavior and trace it back to this condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
```

Here *REQUEST_FILENAME* does only contain the filesystem path to `calendar` within the same directory. And that appended with `.php` is an existing file so the condition is true. But `$1` does contain the full requested URL path that is now appended `.php`. This keeps repeating until the internal counter exceeds its limit.

A solution to that is to use `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php` in the substitution as well:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php
```

Comment: I wish I had more to offer than a checkmark and upvote. Where do I send the beer (or coffee)?! Thank-you so much for that and all your time. Seriously if you have a developer "buy me a coffee" link, I'll use it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you create a rule that matches everything and just have it at the bottom? The rewrite engine gives precedence to rules based on the order in which they appear in the .htaccess file.

Comment: The rules are tested in the order they appear in the file. And the first rule that matches is applied.

Comment: @George Edison: I didn’t say that it wouldn’t. It’s just that your explanation sounds a little bit confusing.

Comment: Possibly @George.  Could I come up with it on my own? No!  I love the principle behind this but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around *how* to do it.

Comment: @jeerose: Sorry, what I'm saying is to put a rule at the very end that matches everything and simply throws a 500 error. Since this rule is at the end, it will only match invalid requests since the valid ones will have been matched earlier.